# What was the name of song which was sung by the choir in "Goblet of Fire"?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, music-identification

What was the song the choir sung in *Goblet of Fire*, right before the intros for the other schools started? And who is the artist? It's very distinct and totally has different words to it, compared to 'Double Trouble'.

Comment: This one https://youtu.be/zAzzwLiroPM from the deleted scene?

Comment: Was this sung by the school choir in-universe or was it part of the soundtrack?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is referring to the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAzzwLiroPM) in the first comment, that song is the *Hogwarts School Song* as described in the first book *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* -

**Chapter 7: The Sorting Hat:**

> 'And now, before we go to bed, let us sing the school song!' cried
>   Dumbledore...'everyone pick their favorite tune,' said Dumbledore,
>   'and off we go!' And the school bellowed:
>
> *Hogwarts, Hogwarts, Hoggy Warty*
>
> *Hogwarts,*
>
> *Teach us something please,*
>
> *Whether we be old and bald*
>
> *Or young with scabby knees,*
>
> *Our heads could do with filling*
>
> *With some interesting stuff,*
>
> *For now they're bare and full of air,*
>
> *Dead flies and bits of fluff,*
>
> *So teach us things worth knowing,*
>
> *Bring back what we've forgot,*
>
> *Just do your best, we'll do the rest,*
>
> *And learn until our brains all rot.*
>
> Everybody finished the song at different times. At last, only the
>   Weasley twins were left singing along to a very slow funeral march

Answer (score 0):

They all finished at different times because they all sang to their own song tune. That was in the facts on the 2 disk.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] to include more detail about what you're basing this answer on? What exactly was said in "the facts on the 2 disk", and by whom?